# Linked list insertion using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

```
//list.h file
typedef struct _lnode{
    struct _lnode *next;
    unsigned short row;
    unsigned short column;
    short data;
}lnode;

typedef struct _llist{
    struct _lnode *head;
    unsigned int size;

}llist;

//list.c file
void add(llist *list, lnode *newNode){
    list->size++;
    addRecursion(&list->head, newNode);
}

lnode* addRecursion(lnode **node, lnode *newNode){
     if(*node == NULL){
         *node = newNode;
     }
     else{
          lnode *nextNode = *node->next;
          *node->next = addRecursion(&nextNode, newNode);
     }
     return node;
}

//main function
llist list;
list.head = NULL;

lnode* new_node;
new_node = make_node(1,1,2);
add(&list, new_node);
printList(list.head);
```

I think I have a problem in addRecursion function especially in "else" statement..
I am getting confused since I started using double pointers...
How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to explain (1) what you hoped your code would do, (2) what it actually does, and (3) why you aren't happy with #2 (if that isn't immediately obvious).

Comment: first of all list isn't NULL initialized and inside addRecursion you do *node == NULL.

Comment: Also: If this is homework, you should say so. (If it looks like homework and you *don't* say whether it is, some people will avoid answering for fear of doing your homework for you.)

Comment: No it is no hw. I normally use java or c# reference based language. I just wanted to practice myself for future job interviews..

Comment: I am expecting insert a new node into the linked list recursively.. and addRecursion function is not working now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace `*node->next` with `(*node)->next` as `->` has higher priority than `*`.

Also in `addRecursion` replace `return node` with `return *node` as `node` is double pointer and you return an ordinary one.

Answer (score 0):

calling addrecursion?? in else. seems to call itself infinitely;

first you set the newNode->next to point to the head (node).
and you need to modify the head to point to the new node.

which your code doesn't do, cause it's using a copy of the address contained in head.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nextNode` is local, so `&` on it gives the address of a local variable on stack. Instead you need to pass `&node->next`, and the return value is irrelevant then (as in the first call in `add`, where you discard the return value).

Comment: I replaced addRecursion(&nextNode, newNode); to addRecursion(&node->next, newNode);